# Mixing build.sbt with project/Build.scala and aggregates

Tags: scala, sbt

Before I had something like this (simplified), using sbt 0.11.3:

```
// project/Build.scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {
   lazy val standardSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
      version      := "0.2",
      scalaVersion := "2.9.2"
   )

   lazy val main = Project(
      id        = "main",
      base      = file( "." ),
      settings  = standardSettings,
      aggregate = Seq( sub )
   )

   lazy val sub = Project(
      id        = "main-sub",
      base      = file( "sub" ),
      settings  = standardSettings
   )
}
```

But I want to keep as much information as possible in the plain `build.sbt` file. So now I have

```
// build.sbt
version      := "0.2"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"
```

And

```
// project/Build.scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {
   lazy val main = Project(
      id        = "main",
      base      = file( "." ),
      aggregate = Seq( sub )
   )

   lazy val sub = Project(
      id        = "main-sub",
      base      = file( "sub" )
   )
}
```

But that doesn't seem to mix in my settings from `build.sbt` into the sub projects:

```
> show version
[info] main-sub/*:version
[info]  0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] main/*:version
[info]  0.2
> show scala-version
[info] main-sub/*:scala-version
[info]  2.9.1
[info] main/*:scala-version
[info]  2.9.2
```

How to remedy this? I also tried to add explicit `settings` to the sub-project, e.g.

- `settings = Defaults.defaultSettings`
- `settings = Project.defaultSettings`
- `settings = MyBuild.settings`
- `settings = main.settings` (sure this one should do?!)

...but none worked.

Comment: The [sbt doc fur multi projects](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Multi-Project) almost has my case. It claims that the main `build.sbt` will be merged with `.sbt` files from sub-projects. It even gives an example of overriding the version, however it fails to demonstrate inheritance, which should happen according to my reading of that document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The information is a bit hidden in the last section of [sbt's Multi Projects documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project):

> When having a single `.scala` file setting up the different projects, it's easy to use reuse settings across different projects. But even when using different `build.sbt` files, it's still easy to share settings across all projects from the main build, by using the `ThisBuild` scope to make a setting apply globally.

Thus:

```
// build.sbt
version in ThisBuild := "0.2"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.9.2"
```

Wow, that *sucks big time* if you have two dozen keys.

Comment: You could do `inScope(Scope(Select(ThisBuild), Global, Global, Global)) (Seq( ... a bunch of settings ... ))` which automatically scopes all those settings in `ThisBuild`

Comment: Has this changed ? The link redirects and the resultant page doesn't refer to 'ThisBuild' ?

Comment: The new documentation links to the 'scopes' pages where `ThisBuild` is mentioned, and yes, it is still valid.